# Change culture on Finnish Windows Server 2008 R2 for Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, location, windows-server-2008-r2

I am making a script that gets a bunch of tags and outputting it to a CSV file. The database in question only allows for a specific date input ("dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") when requesting the tags. However the server I am running the script on is in finland and using finnish culture for powershell. So when I type:

```
Get-Date
```

I get everything in finnish:

```
6. joulukuuta 2017 13:37:47
```

I really want 06-dec-2017 13:37:47

I am unable to use the "`Set-Location`" because this command does not work in Windows Server 2008 R2.

So I need help. When I type:

```
(get-date).ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

I want it to output 06-dec-2017 12.41.23

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -Format paramter of Get-Date

```
Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss"
```

This will return the hour in 24 hour format, use hh instead of HH for the 12 hour format.